# insert stored procedure that needs to reference fields from another table

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create a stored procedure that populates the mail table using type and costperlb referencing the mail type table to calculate the cost of delivery .

I am constantly getting is:24/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
                           25/50    PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here.
I have been trying to fix this problem for sometime now; I have only few hours left. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE MAILTYPE(
TYPEID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL,
COSTPERLB DECIMAL NOT NULL
);




CREATE TABLE MAIL (
 ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 STATUS VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
 DATE_RECEIVED DATE NOT NULL,
 DATE_DELIEVED DATE NOT NULL,
 CUSTID NUMBER,
 TYPEID NUMBER,
 RECIPIENTID NUMBER,
 WEIGHT DECIMAL,
 COST DECIMAL
CONTRAINT...
 );



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_MAIL
(
 ID NUMBER,
 STATUS VARCHAR2,
 DATE_RECEIVED DATE,
 DATE_DELIEVED DATE,
 CUSTID NUMBER,
 TYPEID NUMBER,
 RECIPIENTID NUMBER,
 WEIGHT DECIMAL,
 COST DECIMAL
)

AS

M_TOTAL  DECIMAL;
COST_PER DECIMAL;

BEGIN

IF (to_char(SYSDATE,'DY') IN ('MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI')) AND (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24') IN ('9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17'))
THEN

INSERT INTO MAIL (ID,STATUS,DATE_RECEIVED,DATE_DELIVERED,CUSTID,TYPEID,RECIPIENTID,WEIGHT, cost)
VALUES(CUSTOMER_SEQ.nextval,STATUS,DATE_RECEIVED,DATE_DELIVERED,CUSTID,TYPEID,RECIPIENTID,WEIGHT,cost);


IF (TYPEID = 1) THEN 

SELECT COSTPERLB INTO COST_PER FROM SEANTEE_DA.MAILTYPE
WHERE SEANTEE_DA.MAILTYPE.TYPEID = 1;
 M_TOTAL := COST_PER * WEIGHT;
UPDATE MAIL SET COST = M_TOTAL
WHERE TYPEID = 1;

end if;

IF (TYPEID = 2) THEN 

 SELECT COSTPERLB INTO COST_PER FROM SEANTEE_DA.MAILTYPE 
 WHERE MAILTYPE.TYPEID = 2;
M_TOTAL := COST_PER * WEIGHT;
UPDATE MAIL SET COST = M_TOTAL
WHERE TYPEID = 2;

END IF;
IF (TYPEID = 3) THEN 

 SELECT COSTPERLB INTO COST_PER FROM SEANTEE_DA.MAILTYPE 

 WHERE SEANTEE_DA.MAILTYPE.TYPEID = 3 ;

 M_TOTAL := COST_PER * WEIGHT;

UPDATE MAIL SET COST = M_TOTAL
WHERE TYPEID = 3;

END IF;

END IF;

COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert, at line 24 of your procedure, refers to `DATE_DELIVERED`, in the column list and the values clause. In your procedure declaration and table creation you have `DATE_DELIEVED`. You have to spell that variable and column name consistently.

When the insert is parsed there is no variable or parameter etc. in scope with the name/spelling you used, so the parser sort of assumes you must have meant to refer to a column name - which isn't allowed at that point. Hence the specific error you get - though it sometimes isn't immediately obvious how it picked that particular one...

Incidentally, it's generally (though not universally) considered better to use different names for database objects - including column names - and parameter and local variable names, to avoid confusion between the two. Often formal arguments are prefixed with `p_`, and local variables are prefixed with `l_`, but whatever you do should be consistent and be part of your coding standards.